# Expand table cell rendered as table row to fit table width using CSS

Tags: html, css

**[Html](http://jsfiddle.net/franferns/p8DDC/)** gets my table data rendered with each column being rendered as a table row .

I need to extend this cell to the end of the table, like how it would expand if the td was added as a part of table row without changing the HTML purely by CSS .

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="tableStyle">
    <tr>
        <td class="column">
            Sample 1
        </td>
        <td class="column">
            Sample 2
        </td>
        <td class="column">
            Sample 3
        </td>
        <td class="column">
            Sample 4
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<style type="text/css">
    .column
    {
        width: 25%;
        background-color: Green;
        display: table-row;
    }
    .tableStyle
    {
        border: 1px solid red;
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>
```

[image]

**Expected result**
[image]

Comment: Is there no way to change your mark-up? You are trying to re-create what comes as default behaviour with just a little HTML tweaking.

Comment: Actually i dont write the HTML table its a generated one so there is no way i can change this to normally rendering to a table row

Comment: The point is we use asp.net and create pages with controls that render as grids in order to make it look mobile friendly i am trying to alter it html via css . I cant manually do the changes since the number of pages more .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you can use width: 100% and display: table on the .column

http://jsfiddle.net/p8DDC/2/

```
.column
{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: Green;
    display: table;
}
```

Comment: I've not read good the question at first time, sorry. Edited.